# resizable widget

Tags: android-widget

I am working on an android widget that should have 3 different layouts. When I open it in the android virtual device, it opens with the longest layout but the width of the shortest layout. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are creating a single layout xml file for all three widgets and then changing the size depending on the user's preference (or similar). If this is the case, then you really should be creating 3 distinct layout xml files: one for each widget.

By creating three different layouts, each of the widgets will then show up as an option in the widgets menu: Widget Large, Widget Medium, Widget Small (or whatever you name them).